# module of differentials and compeletion; inverse limits

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is based on Exercise 6.1.3 on LiuQing's book ''Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves''.

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $B$ be a finite type $A$-algebra. Let $I$ be an ideal of $B$ and $\widehat{B}$ be the completion of $B$ with respect to the $I$-adic topology.

1. Show that $\Omega_{\widehat{B}/A} = \Omega_{B/A} + I\Omega_{\widehat{B}/A}$. Then $\Omega_{B/A}/I^n\Omega_{B/A} \longrightarrow \Omega_{\widehat{B}/A}/I^n\Omega_{\widehat{B}/A}$ is surjective, say with kernel $K_n$. Hence we got exact sequences
   $$
   0 \longrightarrow K_n \longrightarrow \Omega_{B/A}/I^n\Omega_{B/A} \longrightarrow \Omega_{\widehat{B}/A}/I^n\Omega_{\widehat{B}/A} \longrightarrow 0
   $$
   for every $n \geq 1$. Note that $K_{n+1} \longrightarrow K_n$ is surjective.
2. Show that $\varprojlim_n \Omega_{B/A}/I^n\Omega_{B/A} \cong \varprojlim_n \Omega_{\widehat B/A}/I^n\Omega_{\widehat B/A}$.

---

I've worked out (1) and I've been trying to deduec (2) from (1). Take inverse limit of the ex. seq. in (1) we got ex. seq. (Thanks to the surjectivity of $K_{n+1} \longrightarrow K_n$)
$$
0 \longrightarrow \varprojlim K_n \longrightarrow \varprojlim \Omega_{B/A}/I^n\Omega_{B/A} \longrightarrow \varprojlim \Omega_{\widehat{B}/A}/I^n\Omega_{\widehat{B}/A} \longrightarrow 0.
$$
So we need to show $\varprojlim K_n=0$. But this is so weird to me. It's a surjective system, so the inverse limit is zero if and only if $K_n=0$ for every $n$.

My question is:

Is $K_n=0$ indeed or what did I miss.

---

The surjectivity of $K_{n+1} \longrightarrow K_n$:

Say $dx \in \Omega_{B/A}$ s.t. $[dx] \in K_n$, i.e. $dx \in I^n \Omega_{\widehat B/A}$. Say
$$
dx = \sum_i a_i d\alpha_i
$$ in $I^n \Omega_{\widehat B/A}$ ($a_i \in I^n$, $\alpha_i \in \widehat B$). Note that $\Omega_{\widehat B/A}=\Omega_{B/A} + I \Omega_{\widehat B/A}$ so
$$
d\alpha_i=dy_i+b_id\beta_i
$$ ($y_i \in B$, $b_i \in I$ and $\beta_i \in \widehat B$). Then
$$
dx=\sum_i a_i dy_i + \sum_i a_ib_i d\beta_i
$$ in $\Omega_{\widehat B/A}$.

Then $[dx - \sum_i a_i dy_i] \in K_{n+1}$ and $[dx - \sum_i a_i dy_i] \equiv [dx] \pmod{I^n\Omega_{B/A}}$.

Comment: "Note that $K_{n+1} \longrightarrow K_n$ is surjective". Why?

Comment: @A.G Thank you for the attention sir. I've added some details at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm sorry I cannot help; I do not know why (if so) $\varprojlim_n \Omega_{B/A}/I^n\Omega_{B/A} \cong \varprojlim_n \Omega_{\widehat B/A}/I^n\Omega_{\widehat B/A}$.